# Добавления URL /en/ /ru/ к директории /blog/ {php}

Tags: php, .htaccess, mvc

Есть .htaccess

```
php_value max_execution_time 60
php_flag display_errors off

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php
```

Нужно сделать так если сесия равна en то добавлять до директории **site.me/blog/** -> **site.me/en/blog/** но путь к директории должен остаться site.me/blog/
в зависимости от языка

Comment: к пхп сессии то вы из хтаксесса доступа не получите, по крайней мере стандартными средствами. Куки вам в помощь, к ним доступ есть.

Comment: вообще не ясно, если вы хотите чтобы снаружи ссылка осталась /blog/ без языка, то зачем вам все это надо? rewrite используется наоборот. просто при работе берите данные из сессии, зачем вам это изменение путей?

Comment: Нужно если пользователь зашол на site.me/en/blog/index.php то отобразилась страница з /blog/index.php

Comment: ну и попробуйте что-нибудь вроде `RewreteRule ^(en|ru)(.*) $2 [QSA]` первым правилом.